# How to customize ng2-smart-table to have a header with two columns

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I need an ability for ng2-smart-table to have 2 columns under a header in the table. For example, for header 'Age', I need to have columns like 'Minimum Age' and 'Maximum Age'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any update here? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I can use an answer to this question as well. I have a similar kind of column I need to make...